# Function to return specific trait subclass depending on parameter's type

Tags: scala

I have something like the following:

```
trait Foo {def x: Int}
case class Blah(x: Int) extends Foo
case class Bar(x: Int) extends Foo
```

I noticed that we have a lot of implicit classes like this:

```
implicit class FooTransformer(value: X) extends AnyVal {
  def toFoo: Foo = Blah(value)
}
```

where in this case using Blah instead of Bar depends on the fact that *value* is *X*. It occurred to me that it'd be nice to be able to do this:

```
implicit class FooTransformer[T](value: T) extends AnyVal {
  def toFoo: Foo = Something(value)
}
```

but the problem I'm having is how to map T to Something. I was thinking something along these lines:

```
def apply[T](value: T): Foo = {
  value match {
    case x: Int => Blah(x)
    case z: String => Bar(z)
  }
}
```

but the problem here is that is that I get a type mismatch, expecting *Foo* and got a *Bar*. This feels like it has to be a solvable problem but I'm stuck at the moment. Any ideas?

Comment: What is `Something`? Your types do not match up and I'm not following what you want to do, maybe if the types matched up? Can you give us some actual code that does not compile and the error you get?

Comment: ... is `x` in `Bar` `String` or `int`? The implicit conversions do nothing but construct subtypes of `Foo` and "cast" result to `Foo`. This looks like anti-pattern.

Comment: @JustinPihony the point is that the types don't match up. Something is a placeholder, in this example either Blah or Bar. In other words, for the generic FooTransformer, based on what T is we want to have a particular concrete instantiation of Foo.

Comment: @AlekseyIzmailov x would be T and thus e.g. String or Int. The idea is that there are case classes which extend Foo with the one variance being one of the values has a different type (e.g. String, Int) and there are a bunch of implicit classes for all the types to add a toFoo function which will take a value and return the appropriate concrete instantiation of Foo.

Comment: @AlekseyIzmailov Going back and looking at how those .toFoos are being used though, you raise a good point. I saw the multitude of nearly identical implicit classes and looked to fix that but didn't consider that perhaps how they're being used should be changed.

Comment: Ok, got it. I'll write an answer soon whenever I get a few mins ;)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `x` has to be generic or a type field because it can be an `Int` or a `String`.

Secondly, you can't avoid defining conversion functions because if you have a function like you wrote above (does not compile):

```
def apply[T](value: T): Foo = {
  value match {
    case x: Int => Blah(x)
    case z: String => Bar(z)
  }
}
```

then Scala does not have a common type for `T` between `String` and `Int`. To address this problem you need to split this into multiple functions, thus you need some sort of implicits one way or another.

Here is a shorter version than what you have that uses already defined `apply` functions for the case classes just making them implicit:

```
trait Foo[T] {
  def x : T
}

case class Blah(x: String) extends Foo[String]

case class Bar(x: Int) extends Foo[Int]

object TryApp extends App {

  implicit def toBlah = Blah.apply _
  implicit def toBar = Bar.apply _

  def test[T](smth: Foo[T]): Unit = println(smth)

  test(1)
  test("str")
  // does not compile: test(2.2)
}
```

Another similar way with [magnet pattern](http://spray.io/blog/2012-12-13-the-magnet-pattern/):

```
trait Foo {
  type Result
  def x: Result
}

case class Blah(x: String) extends Foo { type Result = String }

case class Bar(x: Int) extends Foo { type Result = Int }


object TryApp extends App {

  implicit def fromString(value: String) = Blah(value)

  implicit def fromInt(value: Int) = Bar(value)

  def test(magnet: Foo): Unit = println(magnet)

  test(1)
  test("str")
  // does not compile: test(2.2)
}
```

which prints in all 2 cases:

```
Bar(1)
Blah(str)
```